# Conditional Cell template on Angular UI Grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/).Can you tell me how to select a cell template according to the condition? I have tried as shown below. Obviously it is not working hence first one has been overridden by the second one always.Can you tell me how to do this ?

```
statusCellTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-
if="row.entity.statusDetails.length>=2"><label>[Multiple Statuses]</label></div>';

statusCellTemplate = '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-
if="row.entity.statusDetails.length=1"><label>
{{row.entity.statusDetails[0].status.name}}</label></div>';
```

**UPDATE :** I have tried as shown below.But it always shows the last one.Do you know why ?

```
 statusCellTemplate =
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><span ng-
if="row.entity.statusDetails.length>=2">[Multiple Statuses]
</span><span ng-if="row.entity.statusDetails.length=1">
{{row.entity.statusDetails[0].status.name}}</span></div>';
```

And tried with the `ng-show` also.same result.No Luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Bad.Condition was wrong :(

Here is the working sample :D

```
var statusCellTemplate =
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents"><span ng-
if="row.entity.statusDetails.length>=2">[Multiple Statuses]</span><span ng-
if="row.entity.statusDetails.length<2">{{row.entity.statusDetails[0].status.name}}
</span></div>';
```

Comment: thanks for this - tried using ng-show and that didn't work